# Sort Pandas DataFrame by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I sort a pandas data-frame by column?
I read here [http://pandas.pydata.org/...sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values) about sort_values.
When I run

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(2,'a'),(1,'b')],columns = ['num','let'])
df
df.sort_values(by='num', axis=1, ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

I obtain error
KeyError: 'num'

Comment: Remove `axis=1`, this is looking for index labels that match `'num'`

Answer (score 3):

You should remove `axis=1`, this tries to look for index labels that match `'num'` which don't exist:

```
In[33]:
df.sort_values(by='num')

Out[33]: 
   num let
1    1   b
0    2   a
```

The default is `axis=0` which looks for columns that match `'num'`

Comment: Thank you very much EdChum, it worked. I was mislead by the description on the documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values where is written " {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}" and by the fact that for dropping columns I use .drop(labes=['let'],axis=1)