# Is there a way to extract part of a dataframe using pandas (or other library) in Python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am **new** on Python and pandas. So please excuse my mistakes.

I want to know if it's possible to use a dataframe and sort it with pandas.

**I'm still in class**, but I'd like to advance in my projects.

I want / I'd like to extract part of the JSON file.

I want all the system_name =Métro de Paris to be in a JSON file.

Following are the current code I have (JSON and script).

Thanks in advance for your help!

```py
import pandas as pd

# parse according to "system_name":"Métro de Paris"

data = pd.read_json(r'paris_lines_systems_and_modes.json')
```

```json
[{"id":406,"name":"Ancien M 2nord","url_name":"406-ancien-m-2nord","color":"#000","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":405,"name":"Ancien M 2sud","url_name":"405-ancien-m-2sud","color":"#000","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":399,"name":"Ancien M 14","url_name":"399-ancien-m-14","color":"#000","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":460,"name":"Ancienne ligne A Nord-Sud","url_name":"460-ancienne-ligne-a-nord-sud","color":"#000","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":459,"name":"Ancienne ligne B Nord-Sud","url_name":"459-ancienne-ligne-b-nord-sud","color":"#000","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":411,"name":"Austerlitz-Auteuil","url_name":"411-austerlitz-auteuil","color":"#000","system_id":303,"system_name":"Navettes fluviales","transport_mode_id":0,"transport_mode_name":"default"},{"id":471,"name":"CDG Express","url_name":"471-cdgexpress","color":"#f0871f","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":7,"transport_mode_name":"people_mover"},{"id":465,"name":"CDGVal 1","url_name":"465-cdgval-1","color":"#0a3071","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":7,"transport_mode_name":"people_mover"},{"id":466,"name":"CDGVal 2","url_name":"466-cdgval-2","color":"#0a3071","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":7,"transport_mode_name":"people_mover"},{"id":410,"name":"Charenton-Auteuil","url_name":"410-charenton-auteuil","color":"#000","system_id":303,"system_name":"Navettes fluviales","transport_mode_id":0,"transport_mode_name":"default"},{"id":407,"name":"Funiculaire de Monmartre","url_name":"407-funiculaire","color":"#601e92","system_id":302,"system_name":"Funiculaire","transport_mode_id":0,"transport_mode_name":"default"},{"id":381,"name":"H","url_name":"381-h","color":"#7b4339","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":382,"name":"J","url_name":"382-j","color":"#cdcd00","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":383,"name":"K","url_name":"383-k","color":"#c7b300","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":384,"name":"L","url_name":"384-l","color":"#7584bc","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":472,"name":"Le Bus Direct 1","url_name":"472-le-bus-direct-1","color":"#b20066","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":8,"transport_mode_name":"bus"},{"id":473,"name":"Le Bus Direct 2","url_name":"473-le-bus-direct-2","color":"#7bbb58","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":8,"transport_mode_name":"bus"},{"id":474,"name":"Le Bus Direct 3","url_name":"474-le-bus-direct-3","color":"#0098d8","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":8,"transport_mode_name":"bus"},{"id":475,"name":"Le Bus Direct 4","url_name":"475-le-bus-direct-4","color":"#ff9b00","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":8,"transport_mode_name":"bus"},{"id":412,"name":" Le Louvre-Ablon","url_name":"412-le-louvre-ablon","color":"#000","system_id":303,"system_name":"Navettes fluviales","transport_mode_id":0,"transport_mode_name":"default"},{"id":643,"name":"Ligne Horizon","url_name":"643-ligne-horizon","color":"#0092e2","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":352,"name":"M 1","url_name":"352-ligne-1","color":"#ffcd00","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":353,"name":"M 2","url_name":"353-ligne-2","color":"#006db8","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":354,"name":"M 3","url_name":"354-ligne-3","color":"#9b993b","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":355,"name":"M 3bis","url_name":"355-ligne-3bis","color":"#88d3df","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":356,"name":"M 4","url_name":"356-ligne-4","color":"#ba4a9a","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":357,"name":"M 5","url_name":"357-ligne-5","color":"#f78e4b","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":358,"name":"M 6","url_name":"358-ligne-6","color":"#77c596","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":303,"name":"M 7","url_name":"303-ligne-7","color":"#f49eb2","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":359,"name":"M 7bis","url_name":"359-ligne-7bis","color":"#77c596","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":360,"name":"M 8","url_name":"360-ligne-8","color":"#c5a3cc","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":361,"name":"M 9","url_name":"361-ligne-9","color":"#cdc92b","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":362,"name":"M 10","url_name":"362-ligne-10","color":"#dfb03a","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":363,"name":"M 11","url_name":"363-ligne-11","color":"#8c6539","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":364,"name":"M 12","url_name":"364-ligne-12","color":"#008c59","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":365,"name":"M 13","url_name":"365-ligne-13","color":"#87d2df","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":366,"name":"M 14","url_name":"366-ligne-14","color":"#662c91","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":395,"name":"M 15","url_name":"395-m-15","color":"#a60f31","system_id":300,"system_name":"Grand Paris Express","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":396,"name":"M 16","url_name":"396-m-16","color":"#ec7cae","system_id":300,"system_name":"Grand Paris Express","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":397,"name":"M 17","url_name":"397-m-17","color":"#ec7cae","system_id":300,"system_name":"Grand Paris Express","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":398,"name":"M 18","url_name":"398-m-18","color":"#95bf32","system_id":300,"system_name":"Grand Paris Express","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":385,"name":"N","url_name":"385-n","color":"#00a092","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":476,"name":"Navette","url_name":"476-navette","color":"#000","system_id":83,"system_name":"Métro de Paris","transport_mode_id":4,"transport_mode_name":"heavy_rail"},{"id":394,"name":"Orlyval","url_name":"394-orlyval","color":"#7d7e7e","system_id":299,"system_name":"Dessertes aéroportuaires","transport_mode_id":7,"transport_mode_name":"people_mover"},{"id":386,"name":"P","url_name":"386-p","color":"#f0b600","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":387,"name":"R","url_name":"387-r","color":"#e4b4d1","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":376,"name":"RER A","url_name":"376-rer-a","color":"#ec1b2a","system_id":297,"system_name":"RER","transport_mode_id":3,"transport_mode_name":"commuter_rail"},{"id":377,"name":"RER B","url_name":"377-rer-b","color":"#4c90cc","system_id":297,"system_name":"RER","transport_mode_id":3,"transport_mode_name":"commuter_rail"},{"id":378,"name":"RER C","url_name":"378-rer-c","color":"#ffdc1d","system_id":297,"system_name":"RER","transport_mode_id":3,"transport_mode_name":"commuter_rail"},{"id":379,"name":"RER D","url_name":"379-rer-d","color":"#00ab66","system_id":297,"system_name":"RER","transport_mode_id":3,"transport_mode_name":"commuter_rail"},{"id":380,"name":"RER E","url_name":"380-rer-e","color":"#c67db4","system_id":297,"system_name":"RER","transport_mode_id":3,"transport_mode_name":"commuter_rail"},{"id":414,"name":"STCRP","url_name":"414-stcrp","color":"#000","system_id":303,"system_name":"Navettes fluviales","transport_mode_id":0,"transport_mode_name":"default"},{"id":367,"name":"T 1","url_name":"367-ligne-1","color":"#14609e","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":368,"name":"T 2","url_name":"368-ligne-2","color":"#ba498d","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":369,"name":"T 3a","url_name":"369-ligne-3a","color":"#ef7d2d","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":370,"name":"T 3b","url_name":"370-ligne-3b","color":"#009b41","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":371,"name":"T 4","url_name":"371-ligne-4","color":"#d9922b","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":372,"name":"T 5","url_name":"372-ligne-5","color":"#914e8e","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":373,"name":"T 6","url_name":"373-ligne-7","color":"#e95c36","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":375,"name":"T 7","url_name":"375-t-7","color":"#885f30","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":374,"name":"T 8","url_name":"374-t-8","color":"#8c8235","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":389,"name":"T 9","url_name":"389-t-9","color":"#009cb4","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":390,"name":"T 10","url_name":"390-t-10","color":"#8c8235","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":391,"name":"T 11","url_name":"391-t-11","color":"#df5f3d","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":506,"name":"T 11 express","url_name":"506-t-11-express","color":"#e2562e","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":392,"name":"T 12","url_name":"392-t-12","color":"#a02a3a","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":393,"name":"T 13","url_name":"393-t-13","color":"#885f30","system_id":296,"system_name":"Tramway d'Île-de-France","transport_mode_id":5,"transport_mode_name":"light_rail"},{"id":400,"name":"T Zen 1","url_name":"400-t-zen-1","color":"#c6cd01","system_id":301,"system_name":"TZen","transport_mode_id":6,"transport_mode_name":"brt"},{"id":401,"name":"T Zen 2","url_name":"401-t-zen-2","color":"#c6cd01","system_id":301,"system_name":"TZen","transport_mode_id":6,"transport_mode_name":"brt"},{"id":402,"name":"T Zen 3","url_name":"402-t-zen-3","color":"#c6cd01","system_id":301,"system_name":"TZen","transport_mode_id":6,"transport_mode_name":"brt"},{"id":403,"name":"T Zen 4","url_name":"403-t-zen-4","color":"#c6cd01","system_id":301,"system_name":"TZen","transport_mode_id":6,"transport_mode_name":"brt"},{"id":404,"name":"T Zen 5","url_name":"404-t-zen-5","color":"#c6cd01","system_id":301,"system_name":"TZen","transport_mode_id":6,"transport_mode_name":"brt"},{"id":409,"name":"Tuileries-Suresnes","url_name":"409-tuileries-suresnes","color":"#000","system_id":303,"system_name":"Navettes fluviales","transport_mode_id":0,"transport_mode_name":"default"},{"id":388,"name":"U","url_name":"388-u","color":"#d60058","system_id":298,"system_name":"Transilien","transport_mode_id":2,"transport_mode_name":"inter_city_rail"},{"id":408,"name":"Voguéo","url_name":"408-vogueo","color":"#99d420","system_id":303,"system_name":"Navettes fluviales","transport_mode_id":0,"transport_mode_name":"default"}]
```

Comment: Do you simply want to sort the `data` data frame by the `system_name` column? What is the rest of the code (starting with the `# parse wiki table` line)?

Comment: I do want to sort the data frame by the system_name column. The rest is the other data i need (not yet).

Comment: I have put all the script file, without deleting what was after  # parse wiki table... I don't need it now. I will after.

Comment: I just edited the script file, with the lines that I need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Pandas DataFrame by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584016/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-column)

Comment: No, not really. I don't know if it's a "sort" or an "extract". What I mean is that I need to have the json with only "system_name":"Métro de Paris".

Comment: I edited the title, as it wasn't what i was looking for.

Comment: Then you shuould make it clear in your question what you mean. A good way for this is to add the desired output. Also please use the search function, because it looks like a basic question that already has an answer.

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov, you are right. I'm sorry about it. I thought in the begining I needed to sort, but while looking through the Internet, I found out that it wasn't. Sorry!

Comment: This [pandas intro](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) is a short read and may help you further.

Comment: I read it, thanks @SergiyKolesnikov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to find how do extract part of the data you want to use / analyse.

You should simply call the column you are trying to extract (in my case system_name) and give its value (in my case "Métro de Paris"). Here The dataframe, data, will now have the data with value "Métro de Paris" form the column "system_name".

```py
data = data[data.system_name == "Métro de Paris"]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, include an explanation of what the code does. This way your answer is more useful. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, just added the comment! hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, that looks a lot better.